# Google App Engine User API with Google Accounts

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, gmail

I am trying to test my code in localhost before pushing to production. It's quite basic

```
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        logging.warning('User nickname %s', user.nickname())
        logging.warning('User email %s', user.email())
        email = user.email()

    else:
        logging.warning('Go login again?')
        users.create_login_url("/")
```

I am using a browser where I am already login into my gmail account. So I figure that should be sufficient, but it is not. In any case, it always takes me to the else block. But then the method `users.create_login_url("/")` does not seem to be doing anything: it never takes me to a login page; of course I am already logged in. So it's all confusing. How do I get this to work? Do I have to add something in my `app.yaml`? But this is for Google Accounts not for OpenID, which is the one that needs `app.yaml` attention I think.

Answer (score 0):

`users.create_login_url("/")` will return the URL where the user will be ask to login. Your code must send/redirect the user to this URL.